# MariaDB query columns into JSON

Tags: json, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I've been going around in circles for a while and just not sure how to tackle this using the available JSON functions.
I have a database table with item names and a count  for a player identifier and I'd like to represent this set of records as a single json object keyed by the item name. THis is what the table data looks like.

[image]

This is the structure I want to produce:

```
{
  "WEAPON_PETROLCAN":1,
  "water":1,
  "bandage":2,
  "WEAPON_PISTOL":1
}
```

This is my starting point:

```
SELECT *
FROM addon_inventory_items 

WHERE inventory_name ='property'
  AND owner LIKE 'license:ee7d%';
```

I've tried using JSON_INSERT with a previously defined @json variable but its not being formed correctly. Anyone know how to do this? My dbms version is 10.5.8

The background is that I want an update and insert trigger to respond in each case a create a snapshot of a player's property inventory state which I can then store on a history audit table with a timestamp. I want to capture this json object in as a variable to then use in a subsequent INSERT statement.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Sorry, I'd written out the json wrong, it's not individual json objects, I've updated the question to represent what I need. The version is there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be very easily achieved by using [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_objectagg/) function. Note that you need to have MariaDB version atleast 10.5.0 or above, to use it.

In case, you are using MySQL, both 5.7 and 8.0 support it. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg

So, your query would look like:

```sql
SELECT owner, JSON_OBJECTAGG(name, count)
FROM addon_inventory_items 

WHERE inventory_name ='property'
  AND owner LIKE 'license:ee7d%'
GROUP BY owner
```

Comment: Legend thank you so much. I'd actualyl just got it working with ```SELECT @json := JSON_INSERT(@json, CONCAT('$.', name), count)``` but it does result in a separate result set being dhown plus requires a variable to be updated for each row. Don't know if that's a performance hit but I like your approach better. Thanks again.

Comment: @StephenYork using custom concatenation for creating JSON is error-prone, as lot of special characters like backslash, double quotes etc are not automatically handled.

Comment: I wasn't specifying special characters though, the engine was putting those in. The concatenation was just for the top level path. I agree though, didnt' want to use that.